# How to select points with point ids from external list

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a point shp and list of point IDs in CSV file which match with point IDs in the shape. Points in SHP have location while points in the external file don´t.
How can I select points in the shp according to the external list of points?
Simple question but not easy to find an answer in QGIS 2.18.

Comment: Load your point shapefile and your CSV file as a delimited text file (specify it has no geometry). Then _right-click_ your point layer and go to `Properties > Joins`. Click the green plus button to add a join, select the CSV as the _Join layer_, select the "ID" fields for both _Join_ and _Target_ fields. Your point layer should now contain attributes from the CSV from which you can select your points.

Comment: You already have comment by @Joseph, but may also find this tutorial helpful. [QGIS tutorials and tips - Performing Table Joins](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html)

Comment: @Joseph I couldn't get this to work if the list in the CSV file is simply a list of the point IDs that need to be selected, and not a list of all the point IDs with a second field indicating whether the point ID should be selected or not.  I think the question was asking about the latter.  Thoughts?

Comment: @derNincompoop - If you have a list of point IDs you want selected, go to the attribute table for your point layer and find a joined field from the CSV which contains values. Click the name of the field so that it gets sorted into ascending/descending order. If a point ID from the CSV matches that with the point layer, you should see the values. Scroll down until there are `NULL` values, these are the points which do not exist in the CSV. You can then just select these from the attribute table or use the _Select by Expression_ tool etc.

Comment: @Joseph Got it - the join wasn't working for me until I selected the fields to join in the 'Choose which fields are joined' box (which looked to be optional to me).